# Multi Serving Classes in HTML 5 depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, html, class, serve

is it possible to multi serve classes based on screen sizes? For example, i have a class nested inside another class, but i only want nested class to run if the size of the device is bigger than x.

```
   <div class="pure-container" data-effect="pure-effect-push">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pure-toggle-left" class="pure-toggle" data-toggle="left"/>
    <label class="pure-toggle-label" for="pure-toggle-left" data-toggle-label="left"><span class="pure-toggle-icon"></span></label>

      <nav class="pure-drawer" data-position="left"><br><br><br>
          <p style="padding: 10px 20px; margin: 0;">


        <div class="f-unit expert">          
           <?php  include_once 'helper/block_news_list.php'; ?>
        </div> 

        </p>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

so here i have "f-unit expert" classed wrapped inside the slide in menu. But i only want to display the "pure-drawer" class (slide in menu) on small screens and "f-unit expert" class for rest of the devices. Is this achievable? Thank you for any help. I have looked everywhere and could not find a concrete answer.

Comment: You could use media queries, and make the style applicable only at those conditions if its styling that you are concerned about.

Comment: is it possible to show an example? because is it possible to make media queries to contain all of these classes?